# Enabling Button inside javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have disabled all the controls inside div tag except save button.
Following is the code for it -

```
function DisableControls(ControlID) 
{
    //if(ControlID=="JavaScript:AddBankRow('divBank')")
    try 
    {
        if(ControlID.value!="Save")
        ControlID.disabled = true;
    }
    catch(E)
    {
    }
    if (ControlID.childNodes && ControlID.childNodes.length > 0) 
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < ControlID.childNodes.length; x++) 
        {
            DisableControls(ControlID.childNodes[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling this function by passing div tag ID -

```
DisableControls(document.getElementByID('divControlID'))
```

That Save button is enabled,on clicking it operations are performed, but it is showing as disabled.Help me to show it as enabled.

Comment: No I cant use jQuery..can u pls suggest something without that..

Comment: please add part of your html snippet in the q?

Comment: Can you make a dome on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: in html code I hv done nothing spcl..thr are lot of div tags and in one of them save button is there..I hv to disable everything except one link and save button..succeded in everything bt jst showing this button is remaining..

Comment: sorry @Adil I dnt know how to create dome on jsfiddle.net..

Answer (score 0):

Pass the html element istead of id then your code would work.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UUXGX/)**

```
function DisableControls(ControlID) 
{       

    //if(ControlID=="JavaScript:AddBankRow('divBank')")
    try 
    {
        if(ControlID.value!="Save")
          ControlID.disabled = true;
    }
    catch(E)
    {
    }
    if (ControlID.childNodes && ControlID.childNodes.length > 0) 
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < ControlID.childNodes.length; x++) 
        {
            DisableControls(ControlID.childNodes[x]);
        }
    }
}

DisableControls(document.getElementById("div1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function call was wrong with method getElementByID use getElementById()

```
//DisableControls(document.getElementByID('divControlID')) wrong method name

DisableControls(document.getElementById('divControlID'))
```